# Gmaps4rails : Setting map width and height

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Reading the gmaps4rails gem documentation, I didn't find any way to set the map width and height. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I should have given further details about this.

I'll make an installation rake task to copy css and javascript in the Rails app.

Well, for now, simply override this **in your css** (I assume you didn't change the map id).

```
#gmaps4rails_map {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

If you want it to work, beware to include your css after the `yield(:head)`

```
<%= yield :head %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "your css" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful gem. Just a quick clarification. In your answer you have gmaps4rails_map listed as an id, is it not a class?

Comment: @Seanland: If I recall well, I changed this when I introduced multi maps :)

Comment: What is the best practice when I need to display different size maps? I.e., not multi maps, but different pages whose designs require different sizing of the maps.

Comment: @alieken: you can change the class of the maps, so do this way it's by far the cleanest

Comment: OK, thank you, that sounds indeed very reasonable. I'm just going to add that both the `:container_class` and `:class` in `:map_options` should be set since both CSS classes need their widths updated.

Comment: @apneadiving Could you please update your gem to allow easy setting of map size like <%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => json, "options" => {"auto_zoom" => false, "width" => 100} }) %>

Comment: @apneadiving, the reason I want to put it in the view is so that I can set width using a local variable... sometimes I need the map to generate different width based on other content on the page. Just check out the methodology used in https://github.com/joshuamiller/cartographer Thanks

Comment: You can change both classes, see this example in doc: <%= gmaps( :map_options => { :container_class => "foo", :class => "baz" } ) %>

Comment: gmaps4rails_map doesn't seem to be the css id, but the css class now.  And the container's size attributes should be changed as well.  See Intentss answer below.  I'm guessing this answer was right at point, but things have changed.

Comment: @mmrobins yes things changed when I implemented the multimaps feature

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @apenadving didn't work for me, assuming that the map div classes and id's didn't change, I needed to do the following **(in scss)** in order to get things working correctly, maybe I'm missing something...

```
.map_container{
   $width:675px;
   width:$width;
   .gmaps4rails_map{
     width: $width;
     height: 400px;
   }
}
```

Also with rails 3.1 and above you can simply do the following in your `application.css.scss` file

```
@import "gmaps4rails";
@import "myCoolStyle";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this easily I would recommend you follow this set of steps:

Add a custom container class using:

```
<%= gmaps( :map_options => { :container_class => "map_container_renamed" }, "markers" => {"data" => @json, "options" => {"auto_zoom" => false} }) %>
```

Then add in your css:

```
div.map_container_renamed #map {
  width: 420px;
  height: 260px;
}

div.map_container_renamed {
  padding: 6px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
  width: 420px;
}
```