# Google-Maps-for-Rails - How do I set the size of a map image using gmap4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, heroku, gmaps4rails

Greetings.

I've had trouble with the Cartographer plugin when deploying to Heroku.
I tried Google-Maps-for-Rails (gmaps4rails gem) and it looks very promising. But I've not been able to figure out how to set the map image size.

With Cartographer, I can set the map image size using markup like the following.

```
<div id="map-right">
  <%= raw Cartographer::Header.new.to_s %>
  <%= raw @map.to_html %>
  <div id="map" style="width:658px;height:348px;">[Map]</div>
</div>
```

How do I get similar behavior using gmaps4rails? I'm trying this.

```
<div id="map-right">
  <div id="map" style="width:658px;height:348px;"><%= gmaps4rails(@events_map) %></div>
</div>
```

That draws the map but does not set image size. What's a sensible approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let's be even more precise.

In `gmaps4rails`, a css file is loaded containing the properties of the map container and the map itself. The default are visible here:

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/public/stylesheets/gmaps4rails.css

So you have two choices:

1. basic: override this css (which works fine)
2. A better alternative is to redefine the css the way you want + cancel the loading of the default css file. You could achieve that by passing `false`as second argument of the `gmaps` or `gmaps4rails` view helper. See here : https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Miscellaneous

Comment: This does work but my implementation may be a bit awkward.
<div id="map" style="float:left;border-top-bottom-radius:10px; border-bottom-right-radius:10px;width:700px;height:520px">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails_search' %>
  <%= gmaps4rails(@events_map, false, true) %>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

You can set it via css:

```
#gmaps4rails_map {
  width: 658px;
  height: 348px;
}
```

See the gem author's answer here: [Gmaps4rails : Setting map width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297629/gmaps4rails-setting-map-width-and-height)

Comment: This works. But I have three maps on three different pages. All of different sizes. Setting this CSS makes them all the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm following apneadiving's approach, though my implementation may be a bit awkward, i.e., naive.

In my view I have the following markup.

```
<div id="map" style="width:658px;height:347px">
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails_welcome' %>
   <%= gmaps4rails(@models_map, false, true) %>
</div>
```

I load my own gmaps4rails_welcome.css and avoid loading the default gmas4rails css by passing 'false' as the second argument.

My gmaps4rails_welcome.css file contains the following code.

```
#map-container {
  padding: 6px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
  width: 800px;
}

#gmaps4rails_map {
  width: 658px;
  height: 347px;
```

}

For each map rendering I have a specific stylesheet. This works.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit awkward :) you could have only one stylesheet because you can set the id of the container div and the id of the map's div inside the map_options hash. See here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Map

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it differently. I commented out the width from gmaps4rails.css and wrapped the Google map in a div which has the width-setting. Through this, the map is resizeable, e.g. when using a responsive approach, grid system, etc. 
I use this with Twitter Bootstrap and it works fine. Note that I fix the height so far. 
Hope that helps.

```
#map-container {
  padding: 6px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
//  width: 800px;
}

#gmaps4rails_map {
//  width: 658px;
    height: 347px;
}
```